# Benefits of using Enums over Collections

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to check if a users account type matches one of several `Strings`.

There's debate in the office as to whether this should be represented as an `enum` with each entry containing a different string, or as a `Set` of `Strings`. Whilst the `Set` may be more efficient, an enum may be stylistically superior as it is clearer it is being used for logic flow.

What are the advantages of these two approaches?

Comment: How about [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)?

Comment: Just how important is speed in your application? Unless you actually need the performance you should solve issue correctly. And if you need the performance, you also need benchmarks. If you don't have those, you don't have have to start the discussion about performance.

Comment: You can mix enums and other data-structures in Java: You can put a static HashSet/Map in an enum and add a static method to access it. Fill it in a static block. That way you can you can add multiple lookup methods like (getByName, getById) etc. to your enum.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed, a `Set<String>` is more efficient in terms of performance when searching. However, I wouldn't expect that you have thousands of account types, but several, so you won't actually feel the difference when searching. There's one problem with this approach, though - you will be able to add any `String` to the `Set`, which is brittle.

My personal prefer would be to use an `enum`, especially if you **don't expect** that more account types will be introduced. And if you have a `Set<AccountType>` you'll be restricted with the values you can add (i.e. you will be able to add **only** account types, but not anything, like the approach with a `Set<String>`). The problem with this approach is the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) - consider you have a `switch` statement over a `AccountType` variable with all the corresponding `case`s. Then, if you introduce a **new** `AccountType` constant, you must change the `switch` statement (with adding a new `case`), which breaks the "Open/Closed principle". In this case the neatest design would be to have an `abstract class`/`interface`, called `AccountType` which has all the specific account types as sub-classes.

So, there are several approaches you can follow, but before picking one, you should try answer yourselves the question of *"How are we going to use it?"*

Comment: And if searching becomes an issue, you can always create a static map in the enum that you access through static lookup method.

Comment: You can get the best of both enums and string sets by building a string set/map from the enum, e.g. `final Map<String, YourEnum> map = new HashMap<>(); for (final YourEnum e : YourEnum.values()) map.add(e.name(), e);` -- with that, you can simply use `map.get()` to get the appropriate enum value, or `null` if it doesn't exist. This approach is significantly faster than `YourEnum.valueOf(); about 2 times faster for strings which *are* enum members, and about 16 times faster for strings which *aren't* enum members.

Comment: Or you can just use a `EnumMap` or `EnumSet` with the same success :)

Comment: An `EnumMap` is where *the enum* is the key. A `Map<String, YourEnum>` maps *strings* to their corresponding enum value, which would otherwise have to be done with e.g. `YourEnum.valueOf()` in order to get a suitable parameter for a EnumMap or EnumSet. If you have strings (e.g. they come from a database or external file) and you need enums, use a string -> enum map. If you already have enums, just use them.

Answer (score 13):

An enum would be better since account types (typically) do not change dynamically. Furthermore, using an enum makes the types more precise - e.g. there's no way to mix up `"Hello, World!"` with an account type.

Comment: With regard to performance all instances of an enum are known at compile-time. This probably has an effect on performance. I don't know which is faster, but I would like to see a benchmark before deciding one is faster than the other.

Answer (score 6):

Enums are great because you get compile time checking. Invalid values simply won't compile so it 'fails fast'.

A collection of strings is great when you want to add another option without compiling/releasing a new version of your application. If, for instance, the valid options were configured in a database table.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that an enum's `valueOf(String)` method is implemented using the `Enum.valueOf(Class,String)` method, which in turn is implemented using a `HashMap`.

This basically means that looking up the account type from the string by using `AccountTypes.valueOf()` is an O(1) operation and quite as efficient as a set operation. You can then use the returned value (the actual enum object) in the program, with full type safety, faster comparisons, and all the other benefits of the enum.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like the problem is that you are using a string to represent data that can only have a few valid, known values.  A Set may be helpful to validate if the string value is valid, but it doesn't prevent it from becoming invalid.

My suggestion is to define an enum with the valid account types and use that *in place* of strings.  If you have input coming from the outside that represents an account type, then put a static method on the enum like "fromString" which returns an appropriate enum instance, thereby shortening the window of where invalid data be be a consideration.

You can create a `Set` of `AccountType` enum instances, provided you implement the appropriate `Comparator`, `compareTo`, or `hashCode` methods (depending on if you used `TreeSet` or `HashSet`, etc.).  This could be useful if you have classifications of account types that you need to check against.  For example, if there are "Local Admins", "Global Admins", and "Security Admins", you could define a method `isAdmin(AccountType t)` which searches a `Set` of `AccountTypes`.  For example:

```
private Set<AccountType> ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPES = new HashSet<AccountType>() {{
    add(AccountType.LOCAL_ADMIN);
    add(AccountType.GLOBAL_ADMIN);
    add(AccountType.SECURITY_ADMIN);
}};

public boolean isAdmin(AccountType t) {
    return ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPES.contains(t);
}
```

Now, if you have a case where there are lots of different account types, with many groupings, and performance of lookups is a concern, this is how you could solve it.

Though to be honest, if you only have a few account types and they rarely change, this may be over-engineering it a bit.  If there are only 2 account types, a simple if statement with equality check will be more efficient than a hash table lookup.

Again, performance may not really be a problem here.  Don't over-optimize or optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I suggest using enum in this case. Even mysql supports enum for use cases where you want a column to accept values from an explicitly declared list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `Map<String,Enum> = new HashMap<>();` for maximum efficiently.